# Is there a CSS selector like :empty which matches if any children have display:none?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

As the title says, this snippet:

```css
.group {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.group:empty {
  background-color: red;
}

.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="hideme">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

fails to give a red background.
Is there a replacement for `:empty` that also matches if any children are `display:none`?

Comment: No there isn't. Such a selector would be far too contrived to be broadly useful anyway.

Comment: You could use jQuery's [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Comment: As CSS is about the looks, I'd have thought it would actually be more useful to have a selector that shows if an element LOOKS empty.

Comment: Yes but we're talking selectors, not style rules. Selectors are primarily concerned with elements in a document, not the styles that are applied to them (in other words, whether an element **is** empty and not whether it **looks** empty).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve it using css alone, but you can use jquery selector `:visible` instead.

Comment: A non-JS way would be helpful - there may not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Not that I know of anyhow.

The best bet is JavaScript...and since I'm a jQuery fan myself, you could use that.

```
$group = $('.group');

if( $group.find('.hideme').is(':visible') ) {

    $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color' : 'blue' });

} else {

    $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });

}
```

This hasn't been tested, but the basic logic should be pretty clear?

In addition, don't forget to include the jQuery library in your HTML document of course:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, CSS is getting pretty good, but what you want is perhaps a bit TOO logic based for CSS to handle. This is why CSS shouldn't yet be considered a programming language in the strict sense of the term. A JS solution like this should be pretty clear. You could go this route or try to work something out on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
div.group div.hideme
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

this would style the `div.hideme` and not the `div.group` though

otherwise you could use Javascript as the other answers have shown.